# Python ImportError: No module named pybluez

Tags: python, import, module, importerror, pybluez

I am starting with python recently and I am trying to get the hang of the modules and libraries. So I have one script which has the following line

```
from pybluez import bluetooth
```

So I looked for this library and downloaded from here https://github.com/karulis/pybluez and then tried to install it using this instructions http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-Python-packages-on-Windows-7/

A friend of mine also suggested for me to copy the file of pybluez to C:\Users\Python27\Lib and I did it.

And in the end I am still getting this error when I run that script:

**ImportError: No module named pybluez**

Do you know how to solve this problem? I've already looked in forums but I can't get the right solution. Maybe I am missing some details but I don't know what..

Comment: did you try *any* of the examples on the github. The top-level module is called `bluetooth` and thus your script should have the line `import bluetooth`. `pybluez` is just the name of the library.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 pip install PyBluez
```

and then run the same code, it will run. 
And if you don't know about pip,just google it on or go to this http://pythonprogramming.net/using-pip-install-for-python-modules/

Hoping it will help you.

Comment: I tried to do that and it gives me **Requirement already satisfied <use --upgrade to upgrade>: pybluez in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pybluez-0.22-py2.7-win32.egg** So I suppose that the previous installation was correct no? Also, I tried one example of the github page and it worked on the command line but it still can't import when I am running Python in Spyder

Comment: ok, right hm.. you may have then other problems too but begin with verifying your path environment variable, then look  pip install --upgrade spyder and then pip install --upgrade PyBluez and then, and if still gets problem, then problem is because you have copied the folder, as in python some files are located not only in lib but also in scripts so you first have to uninstall PyBluez using pip uninstall PyBluez and install again using pip. I am 99% sure, the problem get solved. And thanks for comment...

Answer (score 0):

In python modules usually distributed using `pip` i suggest you to install it because if the module you are trying to install have dependencies `pip` will also handle that for you. You can install it like its described in [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#id7). After installing you can install the  module you want like below. It is also explained in github page

```
pip install pybluez
```